# Find $f(x)$ if for every $x$: $f(x) + f(\frac {2x-3}{x-1}) = x$

Tags: functional-equations

I want to find $f(x)$ if for every $x$ (except one and two):

$$f(x) +  f\left(\frac {2x-3}{x-1}\right)  = x$$

I know that the answer goes something like $g(x)= \frac {2x-3}{x-1} $ and in conclusion $g(g(g(x)))=x$
But i don't know what to do from there on...

Comment: Just a clarification to those looking to help, are you trying to write $2x-\frac{3}{x}-1$ or $\frac{2x-3}{x-1}$?

Comment: I mean the second one... Thanks

Comment: @A.nishaburi Then you should have written it as $(2x-3)/(x-1)$ or `\frac{2x-3}{x-1}`. Strictly speaking $2x-3/x-1=2x-\frac{3}{x}-1$.

Comment: why don't you want it to hold for $x=2$?

Comment: @stella biderman That's what the question declares I'm not sure of the reason...

Comment: @StellaBiderman That's because $\frac{2x-3}{x-1}$ can't equal $2$ (but it can equal anything else).

Comment: @StellaBiderman, If you write out $g(g(x))$, you find that $g(g(x))=\frac{x-3}{x-2}$, so we need to assert that $x\neq 2$ so that the denominator is non-zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $g(g(g(x))) = x$, we have
$$\begin{array}{crcll}
(1) & f(x) &+& f(g(x)) &= x\\
(2) & f(g(x)) &+& f(g(g(x)) &= g(x)\\
(3) &  f(g(g(x)) &+& f(x) &= g(g(x))
\end{array}
\quad\xrightarrow{(1)-(2)+(3)}\quad
2 f(x) = x - g(x) + g(g(x))
$$
This leads to $\displaystyle\;f(x) = \frac{x^3-4x^2+5x-3}{2x^2-6x+4}$